# Access dict columns of a csv file in python pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataset in csv file which contains one of the column as list(or dict which further includes several semi colons and commas because of key, value pair). Now trouble is accessing with Pandas and it is return mixed values because of the reason that it has several commas in the list which is in fact a single column.

I have seen several solutions such as use `""` or `;` as delimiter, but problem is I already have the data, find and replace will completely change my dataset.

example of csv is :
`data_column1, data_column2, [{key1:value1},{key2:value2}], data_column3`

Please advise any faster way to access specific columns of the data with out any ambiguity.

Comment: can you please share a reproducible data and an expected output. thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only set the delmiter to one character so you can't use square brackets in this Way. You would need to use a single character such as " so that it knows to ignore the commas between the delmieters.

Comment: but my third column is a `dict` or `list`. Just tried `df.astype()` but still no luck!

Comment: A CSV parser has no concept of those data types. If it sees a comma and it isn't in delimited text it expects it to be the start of a new column. That's how a comma separated value file works.

Answer (score 0):

you can try converting the column using melt function. here is the link to the documentation:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.melt.html